# Sharepoint BDC - Check names not working

Tags: sharepoint, bdc

Long story short:

I have a BDC application definition in my sharepoint 2007 server, which is pulling data from a SQL server.

Some of this data is the Employee Name.

What i'm trying to do, is that when a user is writing a portion of the employee name in the BDC column (in the custom list) and then clicks 'Check Names', it will show him a list of the available names it found. (Like this user column type:)

[image]

now, what happens in real life when using BDC, is that i dont see the list of available users.

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could resolve this problem addin a Filter for the Name Field inside the Finder method, and setting the property "UsedForDisambiguation" with "true"

Ex: This filter applys to the employee name field:

```
<FilterDescriptors>
            <FilterDescriptor Type="Wildcard" Name="Name">
  <Properties>
        <Property Name="UsedForDisambiguation" Type="System.Boolean">true</Property>
  </Properties>
          </FilterDescriptor>
 </FilterDescriptors>
```

Then, upgrade the BDC and when the user write the name and click the "Check names" button sharepoint will try to find the employee using the SpecificFinder (by ID), and if nothing is found then will try to find employees with this filter.

Regads!

Comment: I need to have a filter aswell?

Comment: OK, i have tried it, but its not really working...
What happends is that it shows no matches like always, and then if i click the menu button to look for more items it does show only the ones found... but not in the check names place...